# Using not-default compilier for maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have two JDK - 1.5 and 1.6.
Default JDK is 1.6 (JAVA_HOME sets to JDK 1.6)
and have env. variable JAVA_HOME_1_5 sets to JDK 1.5

I want compile maven project with JDK 1.5, so I added to pom.xml next:

```
<plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
    <configuration>  
      <fork>true</fork>  
      <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME_1_5}/bin/javac.exe</executable>  
      <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>  
      <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>  
      <optimize>true</optimize>  
      <source>1.5</source>  
      <target>1.5</target>  
    </configuration>  
  </plugin>
```

But maven is compiling my project with JDK 1.6!
What is wrong?
  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try hardcoding the path to the 1.5 JDK ? ie `<executable>/YOUR/PATH/bin/javac.exe</executable>`

Comment: Change to <executable>C:/tools/Java/jdk1.5.0_17/bin/javac.exe</executable>
not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%> JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_1_5 mvn install
```

Maven by default use JAVA_HOME so you can set it to jdk_1.5 just for it.

For pom way, you should add this:

```
<plugin>  
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>  
  <configuration>  
    <jvm>${JAVA_HOME_1_5}/bin/java</jvm>  
    <forkMode>once</forkMode>  
  </configuration>  
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because, as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html),  you are missing the `<compilerVersion>1.5</compilerVersion>` in your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this. It works for me.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html